Databricks api list all jobs from workspace
I am trying to get all job data from my Databricks. Basically, I need to put all job data into a DataFrame. There are more than 3000 jobs, so need to use the page_token to traverse all pages.
Here is the code:
from databricks.sdk import WorkspaceClient

# Replace 'your-databricks-host' and 'your-databricks-token' with your actual Databricks host and token
w = WorkspaceClient(
    host='some host',
    token='some token'
)

all_jobs = []
page_token = None

while True:
    response = w.jobs.list(expand_tasks=False, page_token=page_token)
    all_jobs.extend(response['value'])
    page_token = response.get('next_page_token')
    if not page_token:
        break

jobs_df = spark.createDataFrame(all_jobs)
display(jobs_df)

I am getting this error:

TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

I have tried other attempts but getting all kinds of different errors.
Basically the job data will be json like in here: https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/list

The response is a generator object so you can't use response['value'] here. Try to convert it into a list using list(response) and then fetch the jobs using 'jobs' block of the response. And add the list of jobs to all_jobs accordingly. I would've provided a working solution but the Databricks community edition doesn't support the API - so can't verify my approach. But I think this should work.

list(response) not working because there are too many jobs and it needs to do paging.

You can limit the number of jobs to return. The default value is 20.

I end up using Databricks rest APIs.

/api/2.1/jobs/list: to get job ids.

/api/2.1/jobs/get: to get job detail by a parameter job_id.


/api/2.1/jobs/list can also get job details, but the reason not to use it alone is it can't get task elements, which have notebook paths etc.
Anyway, I tried but failed. That's why I also use /api/2.1/jobs/get.
The code:
Get job ids: team_ids below is a group of creators (emails) I am interested in. Can be removed to return all job IDs.
import requests
# import pandas as pd
import math
import datetime
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

base_uri = 'databricks uri'
token='databricks token'
endpoint = '/api/2.1/jobs/list'
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
params = {
     "page_token": None
}
all_job_ids = []

while True:
    response = requests.get(base_uri + endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)
    response_json = response.json()
    
    data = []
    for job in response_json["jobs"]:
        
        if job.get("creator_user_name") in team_ids:
            data.append(job["job_id"])
    
    all_job_ids.extend(data)
    
    
    if response_json.get("has_more") == True:
        next_page_token = response_json.get("next_page_token")
        params['page_token'] = next_page_token
    else:
        break


print(len(all_job_ids))

Get job details by job_id:
import requests
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, explode, schema_of_json, lit, from_unixtime

def get_job_details(job_id):
    baseURI = 'databricks uri'
    apiToken = 'databricks token'
    params = {
        "job_id": job_id
    }
    endpoint = '/api/2.1/jobs/get'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {apiToken}'}

    response = requests.get(baseURI + endpoint, headers=headers, params=params)
    
    # Check if the response is successful and not empty
    if response.status_code == 200 and response.content:
        response_json = response.json()
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Failed to get job details: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")

    # Convert the response_json to a JSON string
    response_json_str = json.dumps(response_json)

    # Get the schema from the JSON string
    schema = schema_of_json(lit(response_json_str))

    # Create a DataFrame from the JSON string
    try:
        result_df = (
            spark.createDataFrame([response_json_str], "string")
            .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("data"))
            .select(
                "data.job_id",
                col("data.settings.name").alias("job_name"),
                "data.creator_user_name",
                "data.created_time",
                explode("data.settings.tasks").alias("tasks")
            )
            .select(
                "job_id",
                "job_name",
                "creator_user_name",
                from_unixtime(col("created_time") / 1000).alias("created_time"), #created_time is epoch milliseconds
                col("tasks.task_key").alias("tasks"),
                col("tasks.notebook_task.notebook_path").alias("notebook")
            )
        )
    except Exception as error:
        print (str(error))
        # the response is not a valid JSON, so it's not a notebook type task, check if it is a JAR type task
        if 'spark_jar_task' in str(error):
            result_df = (
                spark.createDataFrame([response_json_str], "string")
                .select(from_json(col("value"), schema).alias("data"))
                .select(
                    "data.job_id",
                    col("data.settings.name").alias("job_name"),
                    "data.creator_user_name",
                    "data.created_time",
                    explode("data.settings.tasks").alias("tasks")
                )
                .select(
                    "job_id",
                    "job_name",
                    "creator_user_name",
                    from_unixtime(col("created_time") / 1000).alias("created_time"), #created_time is epoch milliseconds
                    col("tasks.task_key").alias("tasks"),
                    col("tasks.spark_jar_task.main_class_name").alias("notebook")
                )
            )


    return result_df

# get_job_details(15770568).display()

for each job id, get job details:
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfs = []
for jobid in all_job_ids:
  print(jobid)
  dfs.append(get_job_details(jobid))

final_df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)

final_df.display()
final_df.count()

